# Possible bug with facebook app settings page while trying to change your app domain

Tags: facebook, settings

My Website > Site URL was "www.mysitedomain.com" and my Basic Info > App domain was "mysitedomain.com" and everything was working as expected.

Just recently Facebook rolled out a new version of the app settings page.

After the new version, I modified my Basic Info > App domain for testing purposes. When I tried to revert it back to "mysitedomain.com" it complained saying "mysitedomain.com must be derived from your Site URL" (see picture).

[image: Facebook app setings bug]

Does anyone know if this is indeed a bug? If not, did the meaning of this two settings changed and I am missing something?

EDIT: I *need* my App Domain to be mysitedomain.com. So the question would be what do I need to put on Site URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it fixed by itself, seems there was an issue with FB. I already voted to close the question as too localized.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a bug. Your website `Site URL` (the input at the very bottom) in the screenshot is `www.mysitedomain.com`.

So that would mean that your App Domain should be some subdomain or derivative of `www.mysitedomain.com`, which `mysitedomain.com` is not.

For example, you would need to have `site.www.mysitedomain.com` to be valid.

To fix it, just remove the `www.` from your Site URL.

Comment: Using "mysitedomain.com" as my site URL and adding a subdomain on App Domain does not work.

Anyways, I need my top-level domain to be the App Domain